# how to check answers stored in external text file in python and validate them and keep a score that is outputted at the end

Tags: python

```
def QandA():

    s_easy = open("Science (Easy).txt","r")
    score = 0
    for x in range (5):
        print(s_easy.readline())
        answer = s_easy.readline()
        useranswer = input("Enter your answer as an uppercase: ") 
        if useranswer.isspace()or useranswer.islower():
            while useranswer.isspace() or useranswer.islower(): 
                print("You must enter a valid letter.")
                useranswer = input("Enter your answer as an uppercase: ")
            while useranswer != "A" or useranswer != "B":
                print("You must enter a valid letter.")
                useranswer = input("Enter your answer as an uppercase: ")
            if answer == useranswer:
                score = score + 1
            else:
                score = score
        elif answer == useranswer:
            score = score + 1
        else:
            score = score
    print(score)
```

I need the while loop to ask the user to input their answer again if the useranswer is not uppercase, a space or not "A" or "B". I also need the score to increase by increments of 1 with every correct answer and to be printed at the end. I have tried to include the score, but it is just not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `or` to `and`:

```
while useranswer != "A" and useranswer != "B":
    #code
```

This is because you only wnat to prompt them again if the input isn't A **and** it isn't B.